# UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath causing slow scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

My table is scrolling incredibly slow, and I think it's caused by the Core Data methods within my cellForRowAtIndexPath. Below is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSManagedObject *info = [buildingArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
// all rooms have been scanned for building
if([self allRoomsScanned: [[info valueForKey:@"buildingid"] intValue]]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [cell.textLabel setTextColor: [UIColor lightGrayColor]];
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    [cell.textLabel setTextColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
}
[cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0]];
[cell.textLabel setText:[info valueForKey:@"buildingname"]];

return cell;
}
```

And here is the allRoomsScanned method and allDevicesScanned method:

```
- (BOOL) allRoomsScanned: (int) buildingID {
NSMutableArray *scannedRoomArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// Get all user_device
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"user_device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSNumber *deviceid = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];
NSNumber *roomid = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];
//int lastRoomID = 0;

for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
    // Get all device
    deviceid = [info valueForKey:@"deviceid"];
    fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    entity = [NSEntityDescription 
              entityForName:@"device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(deviceid = %d)", [deviceid intValue]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate]; 
    NSArray *fetchedDevices = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (NSManagedObject *infod in fetchedDevices) {
        // Get all room
        roomid = [infod valueForKey:@"roomid"];
        fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                  entityForName:@"room" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(roomid = %d) AND (buildingid = %d)", [roomid intValue], buildingID];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate]; 
        NSMutableArray *fetchedRoom = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];

        // add room to array if room belongs to selected building and room not already added
        if([fetchedRoom count] > 0) { //&& lastRoomID != [roomid intValue]) {
            for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedRoom) {
                NSLog(@"room id: %@", [info valueForKey:@"roomid"]);
                // add room ids to array if not already there
                if (![scannedRoomArray containsObject:[info valueForKey:@"roomid"]] && [self allDevicesScanned:[[info valueForKey:@"roomid"] intValue]])
                    [scannedRoomArray addObject: [info valueForKey:@"roomid"]];
            }
            //lastRoomID = [roomid intValue];
        }
    }
}

fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
entity = [NSEntityDescription 
          entityForName:@"room" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(buildingid = %d)", buildingID];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate]; 
NSArray *fetchedRoomTotal = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
//NSLog(@"Total Rooms for Building: %d", [fetchedRoomTotal count]);
//NSLog(@"Scanned Rooms for Building: %d", [scannedRoomArray count]);
//NSLog(@"Scanned rooms: %@", scannedRoomArray);
if([fetchedRoomTotal count] == [scannedRoomArray count] && [fetchedRoomTotal count] > 0) {
    return YES;
}
else {
    return NO;
}
}

- (BOOL) allDevicesScanned: (int) roomID {
NSMutableArray *scannedDeviceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// Get all user_device
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"user_device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSNumber *deviceid = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];
//NSNumber *roomid = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];

for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
    // Get all device
    deviceid = [info valueForKey:@"deviceid"];
    fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    entity = [NSEntityDescription 
              entityForName:@"device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(deviceid = %d) AND (roomid = %d)", [deviceid intValue], roomID];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate]; 
    NSArray *fetchedDevices = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (NSManagedObject *infod in fetchedDevices) {

        // add device to array
        if([fetchedDevices count] > 0) {
            NSLog(@"room id: %d", roomID);
            // add device ids to array if not already there
            if (![scannedDeviceArray containsObject:deviceid])
                [scannedDeviceArray addObject: deviceid];
        }
    }
}

fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
entity = [NSEntityDescription 
          entityForName:@"device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(roomid = %d)", roomID];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate]; 
NSArray *fetchedDeviceTotal = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
//NSLog(@"Total Devices for Room: %d", [fetchedDeviceTotal count]);
//NSLog(@"Scanned Devices for Room: %d", [scannedDeviceArray count]);
//NSLog(@"Scanned Devices: %@", scannedDeviceArray);
if([fetchedDeviceTotal count] == [scannedDeviceArray count] && [fetchedDeviceTotal count] > 0) {
    return YES;
}
else {
    return NO;
}
}
```

Any idea on how to get rid of the latency when scrolling? I'm assuming I may be doing something inefficiently with either my core data calls or the way I'm calling the method in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Thank for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should not make Fetch Requests and processing like that on the main thread while scrolling a table view.
As rokjarc said, you should definitely save the result of your (quite heavy) `allRoomsScanned` method. I'd suggest adding a new style, i.e. with an activity indicator, that the cell gets when you don't have a result for that input yet. As soon as the load is complete you refresh the table view cell.

**Attention: You can't use your default NSManagedObjectContext in `allRoomsScanned` and `allDevicesScanned`.**
You need to initialize a new context in the background thread. Either initialize a new context at the beginning of the block and pass it as a method parameter or create a new one right in the methods.

```
NSManagedObject *info = [buildingArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

NSNumber *cachedResult = [self.scanResults objectForKey:info.objectID];
if (cachedResult == nil) {
    // style loading state

    int scanInfo = [[info valueForKey:@"buildingid"] intValue];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        BOOL result = [self allRoomsScanned: scanInfo];
        [self.scanResults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:result] forKey:info.objectID];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]
    });

} else if (cachedResult.boolValue == YES) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [cell.textLabel setTextColor: [UIColor lightGrayColor]];
} else if (cachedResult.boolValue == NO) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    [cell.textLabel setTextColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
}

[cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0]];
[cell.textLabel setText:[info valueForKey:@"buildingname"]];

return cell;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the answer. I tried the code but it seems to lock the table from scrolling. Any ideas?

Comment: As long as you're initializing scanResults correctly and using a new NSManagedObjectContext for the background task you should be fine. I didn't test it myself though.

Comment: scanResults is just an NSMutableDictionary, correct? I'm initializing like so: scanResults = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

Comment: Correct. Try stepping through the code in the debugger and see where it hangs.

Comment: Failed on this line: [scanResults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:result] forKey:info.objectID];

Comment: [NSComparisonPredicate setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1bef20
2012-03-08 16:02:51.148 Extinguishers[9196:1c0f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSComparisonPredicate setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1bef20'

Comment: scanResults is a NSComparisonPredicate - try to find out why. Good Luck!